# go time.Parse, format "02/01/2006" is valid but "02/01/2003" not

Tags: go

Why the first format is valid but the second not

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {

    date := "21/07/1993"
    in := "02/01/2006"
    out := "02-01-2006"
    dt, err := time.Parse(in, date)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(dt.Format(out))

    date = "21/07/1993"
    in = "02/01/2003"
    out = "02-01-2003"
    dt, err = time.Parse(in, date)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(dt.Format(out))
}
```

Output

```
21-07-1993
parsing time "21/07/1993" as "02/01/2003": cannot parse "93" as "0"
01-01-1012
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Ht0XZVs54ta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common confusion. The date format is not an example date. Each date element is denoted by a specific number in the format. 2006 denotes the year, 02 is the day, 01 is the month. So 2003 is not part of a valid format.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use year 2006 in the format string.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is fairly simple, because the number 21 cannot be a month. Since it cannot be a month, the parser can deduce that it's a day. However, in your second example, "02" could be a month OR a day. You'll have to massage your data into a format that makes it more clear which is the day, and which is the month.

Comment: That's not how date formatting works in go. It does not try to "guess" what the numbers mean, as that is very error-prone. There is [a single reference date](https://godoc.org/time#pkg-constants), and to correctly get a date format you need to write that date in the format you want.